# Stata - calculate difference between prices given in first and last transactions in panel data

Tags: stata

I am using Stata to calculate return data through prices of firms in the first transaction  and the last transaction of each month. I would like to calculate the difference between the daily prices to get the  monthly return.

For a visual, the data for one firm look like this:

```
id         data       Price
220432   08jul2000    .000      
220432   31jan2001    0.156
220432   20mar2001    0.14    
220432   10apr2001    0.13    
220432   16apr2001    0.16    
220432   18apr2001    0.18    
220432   23apr2001    0.2    
220432   30apr2001    0.204    
220432   02may2001    0.206    
220432   14may2001    0.226    
220432   16may2001    0.24    
220432   21may2001    0.28    
220432   22may2001    0.305    
220432   23may2001    0.32    
220432   28may2001    0.33    
220432   29may2001    0.325
```

I need to calculate the difference between prices given in the first and last transaction of each month. For example, we have price 0.13 on 10apr2001  as  first transaction in April 2001 and 0.204 as last transaction on 30apr2001. So the calculation for monthly return is  = (0.204-0.13)/0.13.

Also, it is clear that in some months there was only one transaction (e.g. July and June)  and we need to leave it or move to another cell.

A solution: first I extract date to (day, month and year) and use `collapse` to obtain the return, but I don't know if that would be correct. I think I need to

```
collapse (...) price, by(id year month)
```

Another question is how can I calculate the geometric mean of all prices of a specific firm (`id`) during one month  with `collapse` or another command?

Comment: Please remember to format your answer accordingly so it is easy to read (I have edited the formatting for you). Also, do not ask two questions in one post. The idea is that people with a similar problem can search/find the corresponding question/solution. Embedding multiple questions in one post makes this difficult.

Comment: In Stata, `collapse` is a _command_, not an _equation_. @NickCox has corrected this in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `bysort:` prefix and subscripting (see `help by` and `help subscripting`). An example:

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
id       str14 date        price
220432   08jul2000    .000
220432   31jan2001    0.156
220432   20mar2001    0.14
220432   10apr2001    0.13
220432   16apr2001    0.16
220432   18apr2001    0.18
220432   23apr2001    0.2
220432   30apr2001    0.204
220432   02may2001    0.206
220432   14may2001    0.226
220432   16may2001  0.24
220432   21may2001  0.28
220432   22may2001  0.305
220432   23may2001  0.32
220432   28may2001  0.33
220432   29may2001  0 .325
end

gen date2 = date(date, "DMY")
format date2 %td

list, sep(0)

*----- what you want -----

gen mon = month(date2)

bysort id mon (date2): gen return = (price[_N] / price[1]) - 1
by id mon: replace return = price if _N == 1

// uncomment to keep one observation per each id month
*by id mon: keep if _n == 1 

list, sep(0)
```

You mention `collapse` in your question, so I assume you want to keep one observation per `id mon`. You can achieve this by simply `keep`ing one observation per each of those groups. (Uncomment the corresponding line in the code.)

I assume you don't have any missing values.

Another reference is

Speaking Stata: How to move step by: step by N. J. Cox. Stata Journal Volume 2 Number 1, 2002. http://www.stata-journal.com/sjmatches.html?authorname=Nicholas%20J.%20Cox

The question on geometric means should be placed in a different post. I'll answer here, however. You can compute with:

```
<snip>

*----- what you want -----

gen mon = month(date2)

bysort id mon: egen gmean = mean(ln(price))
replace gmean = exp(gmean)

list, sep(0)
```

(Read more details in http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2013-06/msg00519.html)

Answer (score 1):

To add to RF's answer, you can get the means in three ways before the `bysort`:

```
gen log_price = log(price)
regress log_price i.mon#i.id, eform(G.M.) nocons robust

bys id mon: ameans price

bys id mon: egen gm = gmean(price)
```

The first method is explained [here](http://ageconsearch.umn.edu/bitstream/116201/2/sjart_st0054.pdf). The third requires `egenmore` from SSC.

Comment: Just to add that the second solution requires working with _stored results_ if you want to generate a variable containing the geometric mean. See `help return`.

Comment: Dimitriy, remember to include `id` within the `bysort` prefixes.